# ¿Es estrictamente necesario encapsular una variable de una clase incluso si solamente quiero directamente modificarla o consultarla?

Tags: java

Se que el tema de la encapsulacion es muy importante en java y todo eso, pero hace poco se me paso por la cabeza esta pregunta que como tal, no me habia planteado que quizas no seria tan necesario en casos como por ejemplo en donde simplemente registramos un nombre y ya, hasta ahora incluso para una accion tan sencilla como esa lo habia hecho por medio de la encapsulacion y metodos getter y setter pero luego me di cuenta de que para editar u obtener una variable de ese tipo simplemente puedo nombrar a la clase que tenga una variable y luego leerlo o editarlo como a mi me guste, entonces no se, ¿es tan necesaria la encapsulacion para acciones tan simples como esa? ¿hay alguna razon, por ejemplo, de seguridad para seguirlo haciendo para acciones tan simples?.

Y si, se que la encapsulacion puede ser muy util por ejemplo en casos en que necesitemos validar que el dato recibido sea como nosotros deseemos que lo sea antes de registrar el cambio, pero quien sabe, podrian incluso haber casos en los que queremos que en cierto momento el usuario tenga la libertad de cambiar esa variable y en otros sea limitada a los parametros que nosotros deseemos, claro, podemos utilizar dos metodos setter uno con los parametros que deseemos limitar y otro con la libertad absoluta de que coloque lo que quiera ¿pero no seria mas sencillo si lo segundo lo hago directamente? ¿o si solo tuviera un unico objeto y el codigo que valide antes de enviar lo implemento desde la clase donde lo mando y no en la clase en el que lo recibo?

Esto se lo he preguntado a mis maestros y solo me han dicho que "es por una buena practica de programacion" pero no estoy seguro ¿importa incluso si lo programo por mi mismo? y si es por una practica de programacion compartida ¿porque simplemente en un entorno de desarrollo como eclipse o netbeans se permite hacer ese movimiento de nombrar a la clase y editarla o leerla directamente sin necesidad de que haya un encapsulamiento? debe de utilizarse en algun momento para algo ¿no?.

Comment: No es estrictamente necesario. La encapsulación tiene un propósito y veo que lo conoces así que puedes ignorarla si consideras que no tiene utilidad en algún momento. Pero al hacer eso estarías rompiendo el estilo de la comunidad java donde todo se hace con getter y setter. Así que si el código es solo tuyo, haz lo que mejor te parezca. Pero si es compartido es mejor seguir el estilo de la comunidad para que todo el código sea homogéneo.

Comment: @Lobos Ya veo, esta bien, solo me queda una duda ¿entonces para que otra cosa puede servir la funcion de nombrar a una clase y luego editar especificamente una variable publica que posea? supongo que estara ahi para algo ¿no? ¿o solo es un remanente de versiones anteriores antes de que se implementaran las variables privadas?

Comment: No es un remanente, es parte del diseño. Así como una propiedad puede ser privada y aplicar la encapsulación de igual forma puede ser pública y no tener encapsulación. Las opciones están ahí, luego depende de cada caso cual se usará. Un ejemplo en java sería `Integer.MAX_VALUE` las constantes son públicas. Como te digo, eres libre pero se debe considerar como se hace en la comunidad en la que se está.

Comment: Ahhhhh comprendo, entonces ahora tiene mas sentido una funcion asi, como dijo una de las respuestas, el acceso directo a las variables podria usarse como una estructura de datos definidos ya entendí.

Answer (score 1):

Es una buena práctica usar getters y setters por varias razones:

1. Puedes controlar si solo permites la lectura o la escritura en cada campo. Esto es muy importante, por ejemplo, si queremos tener objetos inmutables.
2. Para validar los datos antes de modificar el estado del objeto (como comentas)
3. Muchas bibliotecas, frameworks y herraminetas del ecosistema de Java asumen la existencia de estos para manupular internamente los objetos de tu aplicación.

Los getters y setters son una herramienta más con la que contamos dentro del lenguaje y, como todo en programación, su uso no es obligatorio y siempre va a depender de contexto. Pero mi consejo es que te acostumbres a acceder y modificar el estado de los objetos usándolos y no directamente.

Comment: Hace un tiempo leí que los *getter* y *setter* no eran tan idílicos como pensamos generalmente. Leer eso me sorprendió y aunque lamentablemente no he tenido tiempo de profundizar en ello, hay discusiones muy interesantes al respecto. Ver por ejemplo [esta pregunta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/284215), sus respuestas y enlaces, y también el artículo [*Why getter and setter methods are evil*](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2073723/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html).

Comment: Los getter/setter no pueden ser llamados una buena practica ya que no son nativos de la POO, los getter/setter son una "solución" al trabajo con los modificadores de acceso de las propiedades, por lo cual, esta respuesta puede llevar a la confusión.
Por otro lado abusar de getter/setter es una mala practica, por que puede darte indicios de que una clase está mal estructurada (La clase no es realmente una "caja negra").
Finalmente tus razones están sin fundamentos, en el punto 1 si quieres un objeto inmutable haz una constante o una propiedad final (en java)

Comment: En el punto 3 no puedes hacer referencia a otras librerías, ya que es un ambiente totalmente diferente. Como menciono, los getter-setter no son más que una estrategia para acceder/modificar una propiedad según sus modificadores de acceso, el get/set realmente puede ser cambiado por cualquier otro nombre y tener la misma funcionalidad, en una librería puedes tener un config() en vez de un set y no por ello va a ser una mala practica.

Comment: @A.Cedano en ningún lugar de mi respuesta vas a encontrar indicio alguno de que esté sugiriendo que los getters y setters son *idílicos*: "...su uso no es obligatorio y siempre va a depender de contexto...". Precisamente porque depende del contexto, muchas veces incluirlos sí o sí en cada clase que creamos puede llegar a ser contraproducente. Yo simplemente me limité a responder porqué el uso de getters y setters es considerado una buena práctica en oposición a acceder directamente a los campos.

Comment: @CésarAlejandroM, varias cosas en tus comentarios. 1) Decir que los getters y setters no pueden ser llamados una buena práctica porque no son "nativos" de la POO es absurdo. Los patrones de diseño tampoco son "nativos" de la POO. La POO no habla de modificadores de acceso tampoco.

Comment: @CésarAlejandroM, 2) Si lees detenidamente mi respuesta verás que no digo que hay que inclir getters y setters en cada clase y para cada campo (que es lo que sugieres), incuso digo: "...su uso no es obligatorio y siempre va a depender de contexto..."

Comment: @CésarAlejandroM, 3) Las razones que doy deben analizarse en su conjunto para entender mi punto de porqué el uso de getters y setters, en contraposición del acceso directo a los campos de una clase, son considerados una buena práctica.

Comment: @CésarAlejandroM, 4) Me parece que no entendiste mi publicación, te convido a que la leas nuevamente. Me refiero a que muchas bibliotecas, frameworks y herramientas cuando van a usar tus objetos asumen el uso de getters y setters para acceder a los atributos de estos, puesto que, como comento en mi respuesta, puede que hayas implementado alguna validación u otro comportamiento en estos. Y por supuesto que le puedes poner el nombre que quieras a un método y esto no modifica su comportamiento.

Comment: Gracias chicos, a sido muy instructivo todo esto, coincidentemente esto es algo que me sirve para una tarea para mañana. Aunque claro, también me sirve para mi mismo en un futuro. Por cierto @E.Betanzos creo que han eliminado tu respuesta (no se si eras tu u otro usuario), una pena, era muy instructiva incluso por si alguien venia con la misma duda.

Comment: @OSTsReversedBackward no, no la han eliminado, esta es mi respuesta. Eliminaron otras respuestas en las que hice algunos comentarios, no se si te refieras a eso.